# Which Splatoon Is Momoko playing in S1E4 of The Makanai: Cooking for the Maiko House?

Tags: game-identification, splatoon-2, splatoon-3

In Season 1 Episode 4 of *The Makanai: Cooking for the Maiko House* , you can see Momoko playing Splatoon from 11:43 to 12:24. I can tell that it's not Splatoon 1 since she's playing on a Nintendo Switch and because Li'l Judd is on the results screen. I can also tell it's a private 1v1 match based on the lobby screen.

Is Momoko playing Splatoon 2 or 3?

[image: Gameplay]
[image: Results screen]
[image: Lobby]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's **Splatoon 2** because of the UI elements seen in the Turf War match.  The top UI element in Splatoon 2 looks like this, which matches what is seen in the .gif:

[image: Splatoon 2 top ui element]

In Splatoon 3, it looks like this:

[image: Splatoon 3 top ui element]

You can see the main difference is the center piece with the time in it.  In Splatoon 2, its a "splat", but in Splatoon 3 its simply a rectangle.  Each icon to the left and right of the time in Splatoon 2 is also more spaced apart (like the .gif), where in Splatoon 3, they are closer together.

Answer (score 11):

It's clearly Splatoon 2 for other two reasons:

- the stage they're playing is [Skipper Pavillion](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Skipper_Pavilion), which is currently not present in Splatoon 3
- the loading animation is a squid drawing a 2
  [image]

Comment: I never played either game, and just assumed that those were random squiggles!

Comment: I noticed this on Splatoon 3, since the animation was different I had an epiphany: "OMG that's a 3!"